# Attachment Editor in XSL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attachments, html-popup, xsl

I'm trying to create a custom HTML Popup using XSL. I can get the attachment JPEG's to show, but cannot seem to integrate the Attachment Manager that you can find when setting the HTML Popup As a table of visible fields.

Does anyone know the XSL code to embed the Attachment Editor?
or 
a different approach might be to resize the JPEGS when opened...

Comment: Is this a GIS related question?  If not, you will likely get a great answer fast by migrating it to SO.

Comment: Yes the question is GIS related, I am working with the HTML Popup settings in Arcmap to get the attachment manager to display using XSL. I can migrate this to SO if that is a better place, how do I go about doing that? Thanks

Comment: This is the place for GIS, Nick, but if no good answers materialize, just flag the question for moderator attention and we can migrate it for you.